# Cant find config files in Jetty + Spring + Tiles deployement

Tags: spring, jetty, tiles

I have a Spring + Tiles project which is working fine and now I planned to move it into Jetty instead of deploying on Tomcat. So configured jetty server to use {    DispatcherServlet} and set my setContextConfigLocation("classpath:spring-application-context.xml"). In my application context xml I have tiles configured and my tiles.xml file is in WEB-INF directory, but during initialization my application never finds it, doesnt matter it is in classpath or not, it cant find it.

My deployment directory structure

```
|- my_app.jar
|- WEB-INF
   |- tiles.xml
   |- views
      | - jsps's here
```

my application context xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.jetty.spring"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Jetty server code

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
Context context = new Context(server, "/", Context.SESSIONS);

DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
dispatcherServlet.setContextConfigLocation("classpath:spring-application-context.xml");

ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(dispatcherServlet);
context.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");

server.start();
server.join();
```

any help ?

Comment: Are you using Maven? There is a jetty plugin for Maven that can save you lot of time. You will not have these kinds of problems.

Comment: I am using maven, but just for build. you mean to use maven for deployment too ?

Comment: Maven is not only for build, it can do many things for you. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Jetty plugi](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin)n for Maven for running your application with a simple configuration and without coding anything. For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.26</version>
    <configuration>
        <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
        </webAppConfig>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then, just use `mvn jetty:run` to run your application.

Comment: I would really recommend using org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin as those are jetty version 7 (for servlet 2.5) or 8 (for servlet 3.0) ... jetty6 is very old at this point

Comment: The above configuration is just for maven plugin. For deploying war files you should download and install jetty

Comment: You mean, I need to use Jetty "war" file deployment model ? I was actually trying to not use war file, but directly use jetty on my binaries. Looks like the configuration is too complex to get it right without using war. i will try to go with war file deployment then. thanks guys